# Can i setup auto sync between two subsites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, sub-site

I am new to SharePoint and need some help and guidance on this issue.

The scenario:  my company is running SharePoint online 2013 via an Office 365 Enterprise subscription.  We currently have in-place a small internal intranet site collection.  In this Intranet we have a sub-site called "Our Tools" that has document libraries, categories and folders in it.  We have a need to setup a separate sub-site outside of "Our Tools" to store documents for hourly workers to access.  Hourly workers will ONLY be allowed to access this sub-site that will be setup.

Question:  The new hourly sub-site will have documents that are stored under the "Our Tools" sub-site.  Is there a way to auto sync between these two sub-sites?  Ideally I would like to only have the documents stored under the sub-site "our Tools" but somehow auto-synced to the hourly sub-site.  This will ensure I do not have multiple copies of the same documents.  Or is this doable by some other method; maybe by just publishing a link to the other sub-site?

Answer (score 1):

You can give access for single lists and even items. 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Edit-permissions-for-a-list-or-library-02D770F3-59EB-4910-A608-5F84CC297782

Now that you've given the other users permissions they could view the files.

I would either:

- Use the existing list for browsing the items.

  - You may have to give additional permissions on some ressources (masterpage catalog, style library, etc.) so the page can be viewed.
  - Add a Link to the List or better use an iframe with `isdlg=1` as querystring parameter (will look way better)
- Use a [Content Search Webpart](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-a-Content-Search-Web-Part-in-SharePoint-0dc16de1-dbe4-462b-babb-bf8338c36c9a)
- Use [Cross-Site-Publishing](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/02/18/an-introduction-to-cross-site-publishing/)